# Cannot return badrequest mvc in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-6, .net-5

Why Can't I return a bad request here? In other examples it works just fine.

```cs
[HttpGet("getPrediction/{dateTime}/{filterUnit}/{filterLocation}/{filterContent}")]
public int GetFillLevelForDateTime(string dateTime, bool filterUnit, int unit, bool filterLocation,
    double latitude, double longitude, bool filterContent, string containerContent)
{
    try
    {
        bool tempExists = predictionService.CheckIfMessagesExist(unit, latitude, longitude, filterUnit, filterLocation);
        if (tempExists)
        {
            return GetFillLevelPrediction(dateTime, filterUnit, unit, filterLocation, latitude, longitude, filterContent, containerContent);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it returns a `BadRequestResult`, not an `int`.

Comment: Your return type is `int`.  So you have to either:  (1) change the return type, or (2) return an `int`.

Comment: The error is already being detected before you code is executed.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler

Comment: Observation - returning Bad Request will be misleading. That status code is meant to communicate that the caller provided bad information, but you are using it for any exception. You should use Bad Request for data validation problems and Internal Server Error when your code is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your action header

```
  public ActionResult<int> GetFillLevelForDateTime ....
```

Answer (score 1):

your GET method return value is integer and BadRequest is type of object ,I do recommend to use IActionResult as return value

```
 public IActionResult GetFillLevelForDateTime(string dateTime, bool filterUnit, int unit, bool filterLocation,
    double latitude, double longitude, bool filterContent, string containerContent)
{
    try
    {
        bool tempExists = predictionService.CheckIfMessagesExist(unit, latitude, longitude, filterUnit, filterLocation);
        if (tempExists)
        {
            return Ok(GetFillLevelPrediction(dateTime, filterUnit, unit, filterLocation, latitude, longitude, filterContent, containerContent));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```